# Different elements same event (two asynchronous results instead of one)

Tags: jquery, events, leaflet, jquery-events

A classic question when you need to handle two elements with the same event but in this case it's getting messed up. I'm using leaflet.js but will make the code more general

An empty var declaration:

```
var markerslayer;
```

The first bound event:

```
$("#slider").on("valuesChanged", function (e){

      var markers = new Array();
      //check if empty, otherwise resets layer
      if(markerslayer){
         map.removeLayer(markerslayer);
         };

      /*some more code here */
      $.post (a.php file here, {some data}, function(data){
             /* markerslayer array is made here */      
             /* add a layer based on markerslayer array */
             });
      });
```

The second bound event (same code inside as above):

```
map.on("moveend", function (e){
      
      var markers = new Array();
      //check if empty, otherwise resets layer
      if(markerslayer){
         map.removeLayer(markerslayer);
         };

      /*some more code here */
      $.post (a.php file here, {some data}, function(data){
             /* markerslayer array is made here */      
             /* add a layer based on markerslayer array */
             });
      });
```

Now because I think they are both asynchronous the first time that I run my script, they both run simultaneously and they create two `/* make some divs based on markerslayer array */`
although I have the `if` at the beginning.

In brief (I think) what's happening is:

1. I create an empty var
2. They run asynchronously so they see it as empty
3. They create two results instead of one
4. additional: When they are fired again each one resets only its own results (it's like there's a markerslayer and a markerslayer_copy).

Comment: Why not move the `post` inside an `if (!markerslayer)`, or an `else` on your current if block?  At the moment you are always getting new markers, whether or not they already exist

Comment: @SteveGreatrex because I want to receive new data from the `post` every time the event is triggered (and update the `markerslayer`).
The first time it's ok to get markers but they generate a duplicate layer of markers.

Comment: In that case, you should move `/*make some divs*/` AND your `if (markerslayer) { map.removeLayer...` into the callback from the `post`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking for the existence of  `markerslayer` before you invoke the `post`, which means that the other `post` can return and create it in the meantime:

To resolve this, move your remove code into the `post` callback:

```
$.post (a.php file here, {some data}, function(data){
    if(markerslayer){
        map.removeLayer(markerslayer);
    };
    /* markerslayer array is made here */  
    /* add a layer based on markerslayer array */   
});
```

This way, each post will receive the data in the callback and then immediately remove any existing layer before adding the new layer.

Note: this would also mean that you wouldn't (necessarily - depending on the rest of your code) need to keep a reference to the markers array outside of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

This code here will not work as intended because ajax is asynchronous:

```
/*some more code here */
$.post (a.php file here, {some data}, function(data){
    /* markerslayer array is made here */      
});

/* make some divs based on markerslayer array */
```

It should be changed to this:

```
/*some more code here */
$.post (a.php file here, {some data}, function(data){
    /* markerslayer array is made here */  
    /* make some divs based on markerslayer array */    
});
```

I'm not sure what else is going on in your code, but this was too large to post as a comment.

I would move the if statement to inside the $.post as-well, that would prevent duplicate markers from showing up because even if the ajax request happens twice, each success removes what the previous success did with the dom.

Comment: You are correct on you code. I have it the same way but i got confused when simplifying it. I updated above.

Comment: @DDL449 Note the comment at the end of my answer ( and steve's comment ), I think that will fix your issue.